# Möbius band as line bundle over $S^1$, starting from the cocycles

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, mobius-band

The professor asked us to construct a non-trivial line bundle over $S^1$ by giving an open cover of $S^1$ and the cocycles.

My idea was to take as open cover $U_1:=S^1\setminus\{0\}$ and $U_2:=S^1\setminus\{\frac{1}{2}\}$. Then, as cocycles,
$$
g_{12}:U_1\cap U_2\to\mathbb{R}\\
g_{12}(x)(y):=1-y
$$
for every $x\in U_1\cap U_2$, $y\in\mathbb{R}$.

I want to verify that I've actually obtained the Möbius band using the "canonical" construction starting from the coccycles.

Define
$E:=\dfrac{(U_1\cup U_2)\times\mathbb{R}}{\sim}$ where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation defined as
$$
(p_1,y_1)\sim (p_2,y_2)\iff p_1=p_2,\,\,g_{12}(p_1)(y_2)=y_1
$$
We can rewrite the equivalence relation as $(p,y)\sim(p,1-y)$. But this is not the Möbius band, since I should have gotten $(0,y)\sim(1,1-y)$. What am I doing wrong?

For me, the Möbius band is $([0,1]\times\mathbb{R})/\sim$ where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation which identifies the points $(0,y)$ and $(1,1-y)$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I take it that $S^1$, for you, is the unit interval with an identification of the two ends, so that $0 \sim 1$.

The intersection of $U_1$ and $U_2$ is then messy, because it has two components, namely $0 < x < 1/2$ and $1/2 < x < 1$. You want to define $g_{12}$ on both parts, and I suggests that you define it on the first part by

$$
g_{12} (x)(y) = y
$$
while on $1/2 < x < 1$ you define it by 
$$
g_{12} (x)(y) = 1-y.
$$

The result should THEN be a mobius band. What you've got a this point is a cylinder (as you've verified).

I'm going to slightly edit your definition, and say that I want 
$g_{12}(x)(y) = -y$ for $1/2 < x < 1$ (and similarly for the Mobius band), because this leaves a "centerline" at $y = 0$, while in your definition, the centerline is at $y = 1/2$; if you were defining a finite mobius band, using $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$, that might make sense (although I might argue for $[0, 1] \times [-1, 1]$ instead!). But since you're using all of $\mathbb R$ as a fiber, it'd be nice if the transition maps were, fiberwise, vector-space isomorphisms, which requires sending $0$ to $0$.

Now my space $X$ consists of equivalence classes that look like one of four things:
$$
L_{a, s} = \{(a, s, 1), (a, s, 2) \}
$$
(where I've added an integer "identifier" to each patch), and where $s$ is any real number, or
$$
R_{a, s} = \{(a, s, 1), (a, -s, 2) \}
$$
The first is for $0 < a < 1/2$, and the second for $ 1/2 < a < 1$. Then there are two other kinds of equivalence classes:
$$
Z_s = \{(0, s, 1), (1, -s, 2) \}
$$
and 
$$
H_s = \{ (\frac{1}{2}, s, 1), (\frac{1}{2}, -s, 2) \}.
$$
(The "Z" is mnemonic for "zero or one" and the "H" is for "halfway".)

In the Mobius band $M$, there are two kinds of equivalence classes:
$$
U_{a, s} = \{(a, s)\}
$$
(the "U" is for "usual") and 
$$
P_{s} = \{(0, s), (1, -s)\}
$$
where the "P" is for "excePtional". :)

Now all I have to do is tell you how my homeomorphism $F$ will send each class in $X$ to a class in $M$. In the following, each line of the definition holds for all $s \in \mathbb R$. So:
\begin{align}
F(L_{a,s}) &= U_{a, s} & 0 < a < \frac{1}{2}  \\
F(R_{a,s}) &= U_{a, -s} & \frac{1}{2} < a < 1 \\
F(Z_{s}) &= P_s  \\
F(H_{s}) &= U_{ \frac{1}{2}, s}. 
\end{align}

It's not hard to see that $F$ is bijective, and I leave that to you; the only question is continuity.

Continuity except at $a = 0, \frac{1}{2}, 1$ seems pretty clear, so I won't discuss that. Let's check continuity at $a = \frac{1}{2}$. To do so, I'm going to look at a "vertical" curve in $X$ and a "horizontal" one, and check that each maps to a nice continuous curve in $M$, That's not really a proof, but I'm hoping it'll suffice to convince you.

The vertical curve is
$$
\gamma: I \to X : t \mapsto H_t.
$$

Under the map $F$, this becomes
$$
\alpha = F\circ \gamma : I \to M : t \mapsto F(H_t) = U_{ \frac{1}{2}, t}
$$
which looks perfectly nice (as it should: $F$ is a vector-space isomorphism on the fiber!).

What about a "horizontal" curve in $X$? Let's look at one at "height" $1/3$:
$$
\beta: [\frac{1}{4}, \frac{3}{4}] \mapsto X : t \mapsto \begin{cases} 
L_{t, \frac{1}{3}} & t < \frac{1}{2} \\
H_\frac{1}{3} & t = \frac{1}{2} \\
R_{t, \frac{1}{3}} & t > \frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}.
$$

It's pretty clear that $\beta$ is a continuous curve, as is $F\circ \beta$. So that part works out OK as well.

Finally, there's continuity at $0$. That's the tricky one. Once again, I'll use $\gamma$ and $\beta$ to denote the vertical and horizontal curves. In fact, I won't even bother with $\gamma$ -- you can give that a shot yourself. But $\beta$ is more interesting. I'll define it for $-1 < t < 1$, to make life a little easier for myself:

$$
\beta: [-1, 1] \to X: t \mapsto
\begin{cases}
Z_\frac{1}{3} & t = 0 \\
L_{\frac{t}{2}, \frac{1}{3}} & t > 0\\
R_{1+\frac{t}{2}, -\frac{1}{3}} & t < 0 
\end{cases}
$$

If you look at $F\circ \beta$, you'll see that it's a curve that runs along at height $1/3$ in the mobius band to the right of $x = 0$, and at height $-1/3$ to the left of $x = 1$, which makes it continuous in the Mobius band. Of course, you also need to check that it's continuous in $X$, but I think that's not TOO difficult.

I hope (a) that this explicit description is of some help to you, and (b) that you never have to do such a thing explicitly again. :)

Comment: Let's call $A_1:=\{e^{i2\pi t}: 0<t<1/2\}$, $A_2:=\{e^{i2\pi t}: 1/2<t<1\}$, notice $A_1\cup A_2=U_1\cap U_2$ and define, as before, E and $\sim$. This time $(p_1,y_1)\sim (p_2,y_2)$ if and only if $p_1=p_2$ and $y_2=y_1$ if $p_1\in A_1$, $1-y_2=y_1$ if $p_1\in A_2$. Then, in $A_1$ $(p,y)\sim (p,y)$, in $A_2$ $(p,y)\sim (p,1-y)$. Is it the Möbius band?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Comment: Why is it the Mobius band? By definition of Mobius band I should have $(0,y)\sim (1,1-y)$, right?

Comment: Perhaps you should tell me your exact def'n of the Mobius band, and then I'll write a homeomorphism between it and the object I described. If you add that to your question, I'll add the homeo to my answer. :)

Comment: Okay, I'll do know :)

Comment: Lots of detail added, which I hope helps you to understand.